# LmerTest::lmer degrees of fredom incorret

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model, degrees-of-freedom

I had a good search but apologies if this has been answered elsewhere.
I am using LmerTest::lmer to estimate a mixed effects model.
I have 50 subjects (in three groups) and two measurements per subject.
So 100 measurements (2 * 50).

My understanding is my DenDF should be

```
(measurements - 1) - (N - 1) - (timepoints - 1)
```

so

```
(100-1)-(50-1)-(3-1) = 48
```

the anova of my mixed model returned 47 so I assume a Sattherwaite's correction was applied.

However, then with another measure with the same model structure and N of observations/groups DenDF = 94. This seems like the repeated measure wasn't taken into account in this higher number as it is closer to (measurements - 1) - (timepoints - 1)

I saw that factorization was a common problem so I checked and `time`, `group` and `subject` are factors (`is.factor = TRUE`). You can see from the output that the model recognises `subject` as a random effect.

Is it because my random effect of 'subject' is so small in this model? It is larger in the models with the 47 DenDF?

Here's my syntax (time = 2 timepoints, group = 3 groups, subject = subject ID, 50 subs):

```
#######################################################################################

full_model = lmerTest::lmer (value ~ time*group + (1|subject),
                             data=measuretp, na.action = na.omit)


summary(full_model)

anova(full_model)

#######################################################################################
```

and results:

[image: results image]

Comment: How much larger is the random intercept variance in the models with the 47 DenDF ? Can you post the output of `summary(lm(value ~ time*group, data=measuretp))`. Also please don't post pictures of output. You can post the text into the question and just put ``` above the top line and below the bottom line and it will format it nicely.